# Posso nomear pastas no GtiHub com caracteres especiais?

Tags: github

Tenho dúvidas se é uma boa pratica nomear pastas utilizando caracteres com acento ou "ç" no github, (ainda estou no inicio da jornada como Developer, quero seguir as boas praticas).

Comment: Na dúvida nunca use caractere especial enquanto estiver trabalhando com programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não só para o Github, mas para qualquer projeto ou OS. Você deve seguir alguns parâmetros do que não utilizar para não ter problemas futuros em outras plataformas.

Vamos lá:
Não utilize esses caracteres:

```
\
/
|
?
<
>
*
:
“
```

assim como, não utilize acentos (agudo, crase, circunflexo, tio). Não inicie o diretório com letras maiúsculas também.

Answer (score 0):

Github tem superte a caracteres unicode.

Mas para evitar problemas é recomendado evitar caracteres especiais.